# Different behavior between netbeans and shell windows

Tags: java, shell, netbeans

I wrote a small program in Java using Netbeans 8.02 (JDK8; java version 1.8.0_45).
It reads an XML file (in UTF-8 encoding), finds and replaces the character "&", parses the file and signs it.

Executing this program from Netbeans it's all right.
Executing the same program from windows XP shell i meet errors about the encoding of the file to be signed. 
Executing the same program from windows 7 shell every thing is fine.

somebody knows what cause this different behavior?

Answer (score 0):

to minimize the distance between this different behaviors, and thus avoiding errors of BOM and charset, I solved in this way:

```
f = new File(PatInputFile);
String sif = readfile(PatInputFile,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
byte[] contentInBytes = sif.replaceAll("&", "&amp;").getBytes("UTF-8");
FileOutputStream fop =new FileOutputStream(f);
fop.write(contentInBytes);
fop.flush();
fop.close();
```

where

```
 private static String readfile(String path, Charset encoding)  throws IOException 
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

and so on parsing and signing the file "f" .